# CDATA error for RSS feed

Tags: rss

The [RSS feed of my site](http://talentsofautism.com/?feed=rss2) is not working.

The error message is:

> A CDATA section was not closed line 33 character 25

with this on another line below:

```
<description><![CDATA[<br/>
```

When I tried to put my blog on amazon and feed burner, both indicated to me that my RSS feed did not work. I validated my RSS on feed validator, and they stated that it did not exist and that it was not valid.
On [my blog](http://www.talentsofautism.com), I took off my plug in and changed my theme, this did not help the problem. My idea was to go on feed burner and put in a second RSS feed, but I found this would not work without the first RSS feed working.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the correct URL is `http://talentsofautism.com`...

[The problem](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://talentsofautism.com/?feed=rss2) is with a call to `colorful_continue_reading_link`, which is not a WordPress function.

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function
>   `colorful_continue_reading_link()` in
>   **`/home/content/42/9357842/html/talentsofautism/wp-content/themes/d5-colorful/functions.php`**
>   on line **`67`**

[A search suggests](https://www.google.com/search?q=colorful_continue_reading_link) that it is part of the [D5 Colorful](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/d5-colorful) theme, and that is the theme you are using.

```
Theme Name: D5 COLORFUL
Theme URI: http://d5creation.com/2012/08/06/colorful/

Author: D5 Creation
Author URI: http://d5creation.com/
```

It appears that something is wrong with your theme. That function is [used twice in the theme's `functions.php`](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/d5-colorful/1.4/functions.php) but I don't know where it is defined. It is [a relatively simple theme](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/d5-colorful/1.4), I don't know where else to look for the function. I am leaning toward calling it a bug.

If you comment out the two functions that use `colorful_continue_reading_link` it should correct this issue:

```
//  Replaces "[...]" (appended to automatically generated excerpts) with an ellipsis and colorful_continue_reading_link().
//  function tied to the excerpt_more filter hook.
//  function colorful_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
//      return ' &hellip;' . colorful_continue_reading_link();
//  }
//  add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'colorful_auto_excerpt_more' );
//  
//  Adds a pretty "Continue Reading" link to custom post excerpts.
//  function colorful_custom_excerpt_more( $output ) {
//      if ( has_excerpt() && ! is_attachment() ) {
//          $output .= colorful_continue_reading_link();
//      }
//      return $output;
//  }
//  add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'colorful_custom_excerpt_more' );
```

That is a bandaid. Contact the theme developer to find out what `colorful_continue_reading_link` should be.